# Long lag between ClickOnce publish and client-side auto-update

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clickonce

I am using ClickOnce to deploy a C# application to a client. Every time I publish a new version to the update server there is about a two-hour wait before this update will be able to install on the client computer when restarting the application. Is this a normal lag time for other people? When an important fix is required this delay can be gruesome.

The application files for the new version are already visible on the file server and the application and setup files have been modified, yet no update presents itself. I have tried to force an update by uninstalling the current version, downloading the application files folder for the new version and running the included application file, but all this does is install the version that I had just uninstalled! After a long while, the update will suddenly install at restart.

So the question is, why is there lag (server, manifest?), is that normal, and how can I force an update to a more recent version that exists on the server.

Note: I *am* using update required version with the publish version, even changing the assembly version manually to this required version. This issue occurs on my own PC as well as the clients.

Comment: [Choosing a ClickOnce Update Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s22azw1e.aspx)

Comment: Appreciate the link but I've already read that article. I already use the "Check for update before application starts" option in an attempt to force the new version to install. However, the application checks for a new version and for some reason does not see that one exists. Such is my problem and I don't think changing the deployment strategy would help that. Do you find that it takes multiple hours for your clickonce published builds to install on client computers?

Comment: Normally, ClickOnce updates are available directly, when published to the update location. Due to this, I'm sure you made a mistake configuring the deployment/update. Did you modify the version only in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: Can it be a problem with timestamps? Might it be that the client is asking for the current version, and since it's two hours behind/after, it only shows up later?

Comment: Are you pushing out to a cached cdn location such as Akamai?